# How to write gaussian mixture model in c++ and Opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, video-processing

I want to track an object in a video. So i suppose that I could use "**Gaussian Mixture Models**" in Opencv and C++ . I want to know how to write Gaussian Mixture Models in C++ . Are there any better algorithms for this than GMM?

Comment: You're better off starting by explaining the type of object you want to track and a little about the application and then asking what types of methods are suitable for tracking it.  The GMM might not be appropriate here so starting off thinking about how to implement a GMM is not productive.

Comment: thank you very much  for your reply.i want to track road sign board on the road(bt no need to identify what is the sign in this step. that is done by other function of the project). by reading research papers i get some idea abt GMM and i think that is better to identify that kind of basic shapes (rectangular, circle and triangle shape) are there any good algorithm than GMM for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to not answer the question directly but:

Reading research papers is a great thing to do, but to be honest, you will get much more knowledge at this point by trying your own ideas on your specific data and getting a better understanding of the problem.

If you know the shapes, it's probably better to use a generalized Hough transform or matched filter for position estimates, combined with a Kalman filter for tracking.  These will be relatively easy to implement.  Or maybe you can find existing implementations.

Also, I'd prototype your idea in Matlab or Octave instead of C++ if you are not a very good C++ programmer as you'll wind up wasting most of your time with problems in C++ when the problem itself is what you really want to focus on.

As I said in the comment, I'd skip out on using GMM's for now until you get a better understanding of the problem and how you are going to use them.  (Unless of course you already have a good idea of how you will use them.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your replying Sir. yeah i could understand that i should try my own ideas to get good knowledge about the problem and i try my best to do that. so i did some coding but i do not know that will give better output.what did i do is first i extract images from video and that part is done  right now. next part is identifying shapes of those images. i do not know this will work correctly because that has two steps than well known c++ algorithms. and i wish your valuable advice for this.

Comment: (other thing is the project should do using opencv and c++ according to the assignment that provided by collage )

Comment: But nothing was said about using Matlab/easy languages for prototyping. There's no point in implementing something that doesn't work in OpenCV, it's a waste of your time. I agree with Chris A, don't use GMMs. At least not now. Get a start with Hough transforms. Implement it. Understand why it works - or what makes it stop from working. Consider some improvements. Consider preprocessing. If you start with GMMs right now, a) what parameters are you going to use and b) what if they don't work and you don't know why..?

Comment: can we use  Hough transform for object detection in a video frame?